# Kivy, python: Dynamically resize text when zooming window in or out

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, resize, label

My code is listed below. While running the application, I want to get the text size dynamically bigger and smaller when you "zoom" in/out the application window (dragging window bigger and smaller). Just like the button as an example (white square). Right now the text size stays the same size.

Note:
If you copy my code for testing, download also [blue.png](http://www.pngmagic.com/bg06/beautiful-blue-color-background.htm) for in the same folder as the .py file.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
    
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass        

class myScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
myScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'blue.png'
                
        ImageButton:
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.25, 'y': 0.18}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.3

        Label:
            text: 'THIS\\nIS\\nA\\nTEST'
            text_size: root.width, None
            font_size: 40
            pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': 0.19}
            halign: 'center'
''')

class myScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

myScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `font_size` depend on the size of the application window. Try replacing:

```
font_size: 40
```

with something like:

```
font_size: root.height/12
```

Comment: So simple yet not easily found. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi John, do you also know how to do that with 'title_size' of the module 'Popup' in python language? for example 'Popup.title_size=(3, 'mm')' won't work.

Comment: The `title_size` of a `Popup` is just a font size, so you should be able to do the same thing. If you have a `kv` rule for the `Popup`, just use something like `title_size: app.root.height/12`. If you are not using `kv` for the `Popup`, then set `title_size` on the `Popup` instance {not the `Popup` class).

Comment: Thank you. I did that, I know how to set that in `kv` language, but not `python` language. My object is `popup = Popup()`,  my instance is `popup.title_size=(<what exactly here?>)`

Comment: The `title_size` is a font size, so it's just a number. It could be as simple as `popup.title_size=self.height/10`, but not knowing what `self` refers to in your code makes it just a guess.